# Color scheme not changing in Mate-Terminal

Tags: 18.04, mate

I am using Ubuntu Mate 18.04 LTS and i am trying to install one dark color scheme in Mate-Terminal. I am following the instructions from https://github.com/denysdovhan/one-gnome-terminal but for some reason my color scheme is not changing.

I already have the dconf-cli installed, i tried creating a new profile as well and then followed the same process by switching to that profile but even that didn't work.

So i am not sure what i am missing here, and how can i fix it. In general how can we install the custom color schemes in Mate-Terminal. I tried a lot looking for the same on google but could not find much information.

So any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I can understand:

1. GSettings / dconf paths are not equal for `gnome-terminal` and `mate-terminal`.
2. The files in repository are dated 2015, so they may not suite for modern terminals in 18.04 LTS. But it works in GNOME terminal from 16.04 LTS.

So it needs some patching. I did not edited author's scripts. I just detected what they change by comparing `dconf dump /` output on 16.04 LTS.

### Adding new profiles

As the result below is the script which adds two new MATE Terminal profiles - One Dark and One Light:

```
dconf write /org/mate/terminal/global/profile-list "['default','one-dark','one-light']"
cat <<EOF | dconf load /org/mate/terminal/profiles/
[one-dark]
foreground-color='#abb2bf'
visible-name='One Dark'
palette=['#000000', '#E06C75', '#98c379', '#d19a66', '#61aeee', '#c678dd', '#56b6c2', '#abb2bf', '#5c6370', '#e06c75', '#98c379', '#d19a66', '#62afee', '#c678dd', '#56b6c2', '#ffffff']
use-theme-colors=false
use-theme-transparency=false
use-theme-background=false
bold-color-same-as-fg=true
bold-color='#ABB2BF'
background-color='#282c34'

[one-light]
foreground-color='#383A42'
visible-name='One Light'
palette=['#000000', '#E45649', '#50A14F', '#986801', '#4078F2', '#A626A4', '#0184BC', '#A0A1A7', '#5c6370', '#E45649', '#50A14F', '#986801', '#4078F2', '#A626A4', '#0184BC', '#ffffff']
use-theme-colors=false
use-theme-transparency=false
use-theme-background=false
bold-color-same-as-fg=true
bold-color='#383A42'
background-color='#F9F9F9'
EOF
```

After execution, closing terminal and opening it again you will get two new profiles in the drop-down menu:

[image: two new profiles in MATE Terminal]

The profiles look like as follows:

- One Dark

  [image: One-Dark on MATE]
- One Light

  [image: One-Light on MATE]

### Revert to defaults

To remove all custom profiles use:

```
dconf reset -f /org/mate/terminal/profiles/
```

Note: the method is suitable for both Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS.

Comment: So that is how one would install any other color scheme as well in mate-terminal in 18.04? Isn't there any standard way of doing that rather creating a custom color scheme by yourself by using the color pallets of the color scheme you want to install in first place.

Comment: I do not know other ways. I checked which settings were changed by `sh`-scripts and changed them by `dconf`-script above. I did not see ready-to-use packages with themes for mate-terminal yet. Some scripts exist on the net, they create custom profiles. Changing many values (i.e. palette) from GUI is difficult and time-consuming. Finally I edited my answer - currently we have three color schemas (profiles) - Default, One Dark and One Light. You can try my script above and if this answer solves your issue, you can [accept it](https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: At least in the latest versions, `palette` is a colon separated string, not a comma separated list - https://github.com/mate-desktop/mate-terminal/blob/f061e35e038cd4df40d9327b9d0931192f0e38ec/src/org.mate.terminal.gschema.xml.in#L229.