# Saving and reusing mate-terminal configuration

Tags: command-line, mate

I installed the mate-terminal package on my Ubuntu 20.04. Then I executed *mate-terminal* command from a native terminal. Next I created some profiles and opened several tabs with different profiles. I would like to save this configuration and have it automatically loaded next time I call *mate-terminal*.

The information provided is not clear how to achieve this.  I used *dconf dump /org/mate/ > mymate* to save the configuration. My profiles description appears in the output file, but there is no info about my tabs.

Answer (score 3):

You are going in the right direction.

To backup settings and profiles use:

```
dconf dump /org/mate/terminal/ > bkp
```

To restore use:

```
dconf load /org/mate/terminal/ < bkp
```

---

Practical example about profiles is available in [other Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/a/1065696/66509).

If you want to have customized tab layout - then [Terminator](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/terminator) may be a good choice. It uses the same VTE library under the hood.